# Create Interactions in Marketing with OData Service CUAN_IMPORT_SRV

Tags: odata, sapui5, crud, same-origin-policy, sap-marketing-cloud

I work on a SAPUI5 application (in Web IDE) which creates an interaction in Hybris Marketing. Therefore I use OData service CUAN_IMPORT_SRV. I already tried it with a simple Postman request and it worked fine. The interaction was created in Hybris Marketing.

The example JSON body for upload looks like this (oriented by [Call OData Service](https://help.sap.com/viewer/c43005898be34c8ca6c433635fbb18ca/1711%20500/en-US/b63250541cd2a47ee10000000a44176d.html)):

```json
{
   "Id" : "",
   "Timestamp" : "/Date(1506014140593)/",
   "UserName" : "UNAME",
   "SourceSystemId" : "ANY",
   "Interactions" : [
      {
         "Key" : "",
         "CampaignId" : "",
         "CommunicationMedium" : "BUSINESS_DOCUMENT",
         "ContactId" : "005056966DBE1EE4B299CD12B99F60C4",
         "ContactIdOrigin" : "SAP_HYBRIS_MKT_IC",
         "ContentData" : "First Event",
         "ContentTitle" : "",
         "InitiativeId" : "100001622",
         "InitiativeVersion" : 0,
         "InteractionType" : "CRM_ACTIVITY",
         "IsAnonymous" : false,
         "MarketingOrchestrationId" : 0,
         "Quantifier" : 1,
         "Timestamp" : "/Date(1506014140283)/"
      }
   ]
}
```

It shall not be discussed if the data makes sense or not. It's right now just a test case. In my SAPUI5 application I started writing a simple function which shall handle the data upload. I oriented on [this topic](https://help.sap.com/viewer/468a97775123488ab3345a0c48cadd8f/7.4.19/en-US/91f2a6ac6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html).

This is my function:

```
onPressScan: function() {
sap.ndc.BarcodeScanner.scan(
    
    function(mResult) {
        
        if (!mResult.cancelled) {
            // begin POST Interaction with OData
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("https://host:port/sap/opu/odata/sap/CUAN_IMPORT_SRV/", true, "UNAME", "PASSWORD");
            oModel.setHeaders({
                "X-CSRF-Token" : "Fetch"
            });
            
            var jsonString = '{ "Id" : "", "Timestamp" : "/Date(1506014140591)/",  "UserName" : "UNAME", "SourceSystemId" : "ANY", "Interactions" : [ ' +
            '{ "Key" : "" , "CampaignId" : "" , "CommunicationMedium" : "BUSINESS_DOCUMENT" , "ContactId" : "005056966DBE1EE4B299CD12B99F60D4" ' +
            ', "ContactIdOrigin" : "SAP_HYBRIS_MKT_IC" , "ContentData" : "Try from Scanner App", "ContentTitle" : "Scan", "InitiativeId" : "100001622" ' +
            ', "InitiativeVersion" : 0, "InteractionType" : "CRM_ACTIVITY", "IsAnonymous" : false, "MarketingOrchestrationId" : 0, "Quantifier" : 1, "Timestamp" : "/Date(1506014140281)/" }]}';
            
            var json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        
            // get X-CSRF-Token for POST request
            oModel.read("/$metadata", null, null, true, function(oData, oResponse) {

            var xcsrfToken = oResponse.headers["x-csrf-token"];

            oModel.setHeaders({
                "X-CSRF-Token" : xcsrfToken,
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            });

            // POST interaction to yMarketing
            oModel.create("/ImportHeaders", json, null, function() {
                alert("Create successful");
            }, function(){
                alert("Create failed");
            });
        }, function() {
            alert("Read failed");
        });
    }}, function(Error) {
        sap.m.MessageBox.error("Scanning failed due to following error: " + Error, {
            title: "Error while scanning"                                     
        });
    }
);
```

}

When I try the application I get the following error:

[image: error]

When declaring the OData Model I use a correct system UNAME and PASSWORD for reading and writing. What do I do wrong?

Any hints well appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Click Chrome Icon > Options > Add this behind your target path:

> --disable-web-security --user-data-dir